# CSS within <DIV> Tags

Tags: html, css

I am taking an online course and learning javascript, html5 and CSS. I am having an issue with getting my table to be formatted with my css file. It is inside a DIV tag:

```
<div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
```

I am trying to do with my CSS:

```
table th, td { border: 1px solid black;}
```

And I tried doing .ui-content table th, td {} and nothing and I tried a few others, but I am still stuck with it. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Could you put together a quick demo in jsfiddle or codepen? There are a few things it could be. I'd want to make sure the css is linked properly. The css you have there should be changing the styles on the elements.

The `,` would make two rules `table th` and `td`. Is that how you're meaning to group it?

Comment: The styles that you defined for table but where is table in your html tag

Comment: The problem is that your table tag doesn't have a `.ui-content` style

Comment: Within the <head></head> tags I have: <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

Comment: <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
      <table></table>

Answer (score 2):

When have space between element you are targeting children of that element while when you have commas you are targeting multiple elements.

In your case to be able to apply a border to the `th`, `td` and `table` you would need to do:

```css
table, th, td { border: 1px solid black;}
```

But if you want to apply the css to the `th` and `td` inside of a `table` element you would need to do

```css
table td { border: 1px solid black;}
table th { border: 1px solid black;}
```

With the html you have

```html
<div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <table>
        <tr>
          <th>Grade</th>
          <th>Numeric Equivalent</th>
          <th>Explanation</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>A</td>
          <td>95-100</td>
          <td><strong>Excellent.</strong></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Your css should be

```css
table { border-collapse: collapse; }
table th { border: 1px solid black; }
table td { border: 1px solid black; }
```

Comment: Edit your own question to show us what code you have currently instead of one of the answers @cstickman

Answer (score 1):

Here's vary basic sample, now may be tell what's the problem

```css
table, th, td { border: 1px solid black;}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Header 1
        </th>
        <th>
            Header 2
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Data 1
        </td>
        <td>
            Data 2
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Data 1
        </td>
        <td>
            Data 2
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```